# Vuejs: watching for query params change

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pagination, vuejs3, vue-router

I'm trying to watch for query param change, and if it does, assign a new value to the `page.number` (page is a reactive object), and then load data. However, I end up with a weird behavior:

- when I click on next page in the pagination, I get 2 requests: `/recipe?page=1&pageSize=3` and `/recipe?page=2&pageSize=3` and it still shows `?page=1` in the url. Then if I click again, the request is `recipe?page=2&pageSize=3`, but it still shows `?page=1` in the url. If I click third time I can see the requests `/recipe?page=2&pageSize=3` and `/recipe?page=3&pageSize=3` and now it's `?page=2` in the url. Why does it make 2 requests and why do I need to make so many clicks to get to page 2?

I tried 2 approaches, first is using `watch`:

```js
watch(
    () => route.query.page,
    async newPage => {
        page.number = newPage;
        await loadRecipes();
        console.log('newPage', newPage);
    }
);
```

and second is using `onBeforeRouteUpdate`:

```js
onBeforeRouteUpdate(async (to, from, next) => {
    if (to.query.page !== from.query.page) {
        page.number = to.query.page;
        await loadRecipes();
    }
    next();
});
```

Both worked similarly.

`toNextPage` function:

```js
const toNextPage = async () => {
    page.number++;
    await loadRecipes();
};
```

`onMounted` hook:

```
onMounted(async () => {
    await storeRecipe.loadRecipesCount();
    await loadRecipes();
});
```

Pagination:

```
<ul class="pagination__list">
    <li class="pagination__item">
        <router-link
            :to="{
                 query: {
                 page: page.number,
                 },
            }"
            class="pagination__link"
            v-for="pageNumber in totalPages"
            :key="pageNumber"
            :class="{ active: pageNumber === page.number }"
            @click="toSpecificPage(pageNumber)"
        >
            {{ pageNumber }}
        </router-link>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I also use Pinia store.

What am I doing wrong? Please, give me a solution. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: Why are you assigning the `page.number` that way though? Try putting a debugger on the watcher and see if it triggers twice.